# I Injected the service Interface in Resource but not able to figure out how to configure Resource Method Calling

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard, inject

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSfP8.png)This is the code I wrote to start the Resource. Not able to register the Resouce Class. Used Mongo database and the basics of @Injected

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Student extends BaseModel {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String marks;
    private long dob;
    @Email
    private String email;


    public Student() {
    }

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String marks, long dob, @Email String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.marks = marks;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.email = email;
    }
//Getter Setter method 
}

//Base Repository Interface
public interface BaseRepository<T extends BaseModel> extends GenericRepository<T> {

    T save (T model);
    List<T> getAll();
    T getById(String Id);
    void deleteById(String Id);
    T updateById(String Id, T model);
}
```

Abstract Repository Method to perform the Basics method of CRUD Operation

```
 public BaseRepositoryImpl(MongoDb mongoManager, Class<T> clazz) throws Exception{
        this.mongoManager = mongoManager;
        collectionName = clazz.getAnnotation(CollectionName.class);
        collection = mongoManager.getMongoCollection(collectionName.name());
        entityClass = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public T save(T model) {
        if(model == null){
            throw new RuntimeException("No data Found");
        }
        Object id = collection.save(model).getUpsertedId();
        if(id != null && id instanceof ObjectId){
            model.setId(((ObjectId) id).toStringMongod());
        }
        return model;
    }
}

//service
public interface StudentService {
    Student save(Student student);
}


//Resource 
WebService
@Path("/student")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@HK2Managed
@Timed
public class StudentResource {


    @Inject
    StudentService studentService;

   /* @Inject
    public StudentResource(StudentService studentService) {
        this.studentService = studentService;
    }*/

    @Path("/getName")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String getName(){
        return "Puru";
    }
}
```

Configuration of the Application to Register the Uri and port of the Main Class

```
    private String template;
    // private StudentService studentService;

    private String defaultName = "Stranger";

    public MongoConfiguration getMongoConfiguration() {
        return mongoConfiguration;
    }

    public void setMongoConfiguration(MongoConfiguration mongoConfiguration) {
        this.mongoConfiguration = mongoConfiguration;
    }


    @Valid
    @JsonProperty("mongoserver")
    public MongoConfiguration mongoConfiguration;
}

//Application Connector  to bind the Class in interface of the Respected Class 

public class ApplicationConnector extends AbstractModule /*AbstractBinder*/ {

    private final ConfigurationContext context;

    public ApplicationConnector(ConfigurationContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(StudentService.class).to(StudentServiceImpl.class);
        bind(StudentRepository.class).to(StudentRepositoryImpl.class);
    }

// applicaytion Connector Class 

public class App extends Application<AppConfiguration> {

    GuiceBundle<AppConfiguration> guiceBundle = null;
    private JAXWSBundle jaxwsBundle = new JAXWSBundle();
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        new App().run(args);
    }
    private JAXWSBundle<Object> jaxWsBundle = new JAXWSBundle<>("/api");
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "student-DropWizard-demo";
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(final Bootstrap<AppConfiguration> bootstrap) {
        // TODO: application initializatio
//        bootstrap.getObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
//        bootstrap.addBundle(GuiceBundle.<AppConfiguration>builder()
//                .enableAutoConfig("package.to.scan")
//                .searchCommands(true)
//                .build()
//        );
             /*  GuiceBundle.Builder builder = GuiceBundle.builder() .noDefaultInstallers()
                .enableAutoConfig("com.dzone");
               guiceBundle = builder.build();*/
//        bootstrap.addBundle(GuiceBundle.builder().enableAutoConfig("com.dzone")
//                .build());

      //  Module[] modules = autoDiscoverModules();


        bootstrap.getObjectMapper().registerSubtypes(DefaultServerFactory.class);
//bootstrap.getObjectMapper().registerModule(new FCSerializerModule());
        bootstrap.getObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationFeature.READ_ENUMS_USING_TO_STRING);
        bootstrap.addBundle(jaxwsBundle);
        GuiceBundle.Builder builder = GuiceBundle.builder()
//                .modules(modules)
                .noDefaultInstallers()
                .installers(new Class[]{LifeCycleInstaller.class,
                        ManagedInstaller.class,
                        JerseyFeatureInstaller.class, ResourceInstaller.class,
                        JerseyProviderInstaller.class,
                        EagerSingletonInstaller.class,
                        HealthCheckInstaller.class,
                        TaskInstaller.class,
                        PluginInstaller.class
                })
                .enableAutoConfig(ApplicationConnector.class.getPackage().getName());
        postInitialize(bootstrap, builder);
        guiceBundle = builder.build();
        bootstrap.addBundle(guiceBundle);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(final AppConfiguration configuration,
                    final Environment environment) throws Exception {
        // TODO: implement application
      //  FilterRegistration.Dynamic dFilter = environment.servlets().addFilter("student", CrossOriginFilter.class);
//   AbstractServerFactory sf = (AbstractServerFactory) configuration.getServerFactory();

//        Endpoint e =  jaxWsBundle.publishEndpoint(
//                new EndpointBuilder("student", new StudentResource()));
       // environment.jersey().register(new StudentResource());
        //environment.jersey().register(new StudentServiceImpl());
        //environment.jersey().packages("service");
      //  environment.jersey().disable();
       // environment.servlets().addServlet(StudentResource.class).addMapping("/student");
        environment.getJerseyServletContainer().getServletInfo();
        //environment.servlets().setBaseResource("");
        ///environment.servlets().addServlet("StudentResource",StudentResource.class);
       //environment.jersey().register(new ResourceInstaller());

        postRun(configuration,environment);
    }

    protected void postRun(final AppConfiguration configuration, final Environment environment) throws Exception {
        // Sub-classes should
    }

    protected void postInitialize(Bootstrap<AppConfiguration> bootstrapm, GuiceBundle.Builder guiceBuilder) {
        // Sub-classes should
    }
 /*public Module[] autoDiscoverModules() {
        Reflections reflections =
                new Reflections(
                        new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                .forPackages(
                                       "com.dzone"));

        Set<Class<? extends AbstractModule>> classes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(AbstractModule.class);

        List<Module> discoveredModules = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Class clazz : classes) {
            try {
                AbstractModule module = (AbstractModule) clazz.newInstance();
                discoveredModules.add(module);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return discoveredModules.toArray(new Module[]{});
    }
}
```

This is the output of the Code. It's not able to register the the resource of the application

```
WARN  [2019-09-09 05:32:31,707] io.dropwizard.setup.AdminEnvironment: 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!    THIS APPLICATION HAS NO HEALTHCHECKS. THIS MEANS YOU WILL NEVER KNOW      !
!     IF IT DIES IN PRODUCTION, WHICH MEANS YOU WILL NEVER KNOW IF YOU'RE      !
!    LETTING YOUR USERS DOWN. YOU SHOULD ADD A HEALTHCHECK FOR EACH OF YOUR    !
!         APPLICATION'S DEPENDENCIES WHICH FULLY (BUT LIGHTLY) TESTS IT.       !
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
INFO  [2019-09-09 05:32:31,711] org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler: Started i.d.j.MutableServletContextHandler@615db358{/,null,AVAILABLE}
INFO  [2019-09-09 05:32:31,718] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started application@f9cab00{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8099}
INFO  [2019-09-09 05:32:31,719] org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector: Started admin@10272bbb{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8091}
INFO  [2019-09-09 05:32:31,719] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server: Started @5573ms
INFO  [2019-09-09 05:32:31,719] com.roskart.dropwizard.jaxws.JAXWSEnvironment: No JAX-WS service endpoints were registered.
```

[image]

Comment: JAX-WS is not part of Dropwizard, support for it is provided by [an extension](https://github.com/roskart/dropwizard-jaxws). You seem to use this extension, correct? What happens if you uncomment the line `jaxWsBundle.publishEndpoint(new EndpointBuilder("student", new StudentResource()));`?

Comment: com.roskart.dropwizard.jaxws.JAXWSEnvironment.publishEndpoint(JAXWSEnvironment.java:135)
 at com.roskart.dropwizard.jaxws.JAXWSBundle.publishEndpoint(JAXWSBundle.java:85)
 at App.run(App.java:97)
 at App.run(App.java:37)
 at io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:43)
 at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:87)
 at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:78)
 at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:93)
 at App.main(App.java:42)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the actual code you use and the error.

Comment: https://github.com/Purushottam10/student-gradle here is the project i'm not able to figure out actuall error

Answer (score 0):

In the example above you declare Resource as HK managed:

```java
@HK2Managed
@Timed
public class StudentResource {
```

Which means that HK2 (jersey's DI) will instantiate object and not guice.

But your service is declared in guice module:

```java
public class ApplicationConnector extends AbstractModule /*AbstractBinder*/ {

    private final ConfigurationContext context;

    public ApplicationConnector(ConfigurationContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(StudentService.class).to(StudentServiceImpl.class);
        bind(StudentRepository.class).to(StudentRepositoryImpl.class);
    }
```

So it's normal that your service can't inject `StudentService` as HK2 is not aware of guice dependencies.

This could be fixed by [activating HK2-guice bridge](http://xvik.github.io/dropwizard-guicey/4.2.2/guide/configuration/#hk2-bridge) so HK could use guice bindings:

- Add dependency: org.glassfish.hk2:guice-bridge:2.5.0-b32 (version must match HK2 version, used by dropwizard)
- Enable option: .option(GuiceyOptions.UseHkBridge, true)

---

In your github project ([student-gradle](https://github.com/Purushottam10/student-gradle)) you have an opposite situation:

Resource is guice managed (guice creates resource instance)

```java
@Path("/student")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Timed
public class StudentResource {
```

And service is declared in HK:

```java
public class ApplicationConnector extends /*AbstractModule*/ AbstractBinder {
    @PostConstruct
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(StudentService.class).to(StudentServiceImpl.class);
        bind(StudentRepository.class).to(StudentRepositoryImpl.class);
    }
}
```

(but this module is actually never registered)

My suggestion is to "live" in guice context: don't use `@HKManaged` (it was added only for edge cases) and use guice modules for services declaration. This way guice will be responsible for all DI related to your code.